# Calc2 Slicing method to find volume

Tags: calculus

> The base is a circle of radius 2;  slices made perpendicular to the base are squares.  See the figure.
>
> [image]
>
> Answer: $\dfrac{128}3$

The answer is given but I can't figure out how to get it.  Here's what I've done:

I need to find the area of the slice (square) and I *know* this is $x^2$.  I then take the integral from $-2$ to $2$ of $x^2\ \mathrm dx$.  The integral becomes $\frac{x^3}3$.  I evaluate this at $2$ and $-2$ and get $\frac{16}3$.  The correct answer is $128/3$.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my first slice problem so I'm probably way off.  All the videos I've watched go the same way but they start with the correct function so I can only assume $x^2$ is wrong in this case somehow (problem doesn't give me the function but a square should be $x^2$ right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight is to ask, "what is the side length of a representative square **as a function of its distance from the origin**?"

By integrating $x^2$ from $x = -2$ to $2$, you've effectively ignored the fact that, for example, the side length of the square gets smaller, not larger, the further away it is from the origin.  This is evidenced by the circular base on which the volume of interest lies.

To be more specific, consider a representative square of differential thickness $dx$, whose edge along the circular base is perpendicular to the $x$-axis and intersects this axis at coordinate $(x,0)$.  Then as a function of $x$, the side length of this square is $2 \sqrt{2^2 - x^2}$.  Therefore, the differential volume of this representative square slice is $$dV = \left(2 \sqrt{2^2 - x^2}\right)^2 \, dx = 4 (4-x^2) \, dx$$ and the total volume is $$V = \int_{x=-2}^2 dV = 4 \int_{x=-2}^2 (4-x^2) \, dx.$$