# Volume of a solid by slicing

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I am so confused on how to find the height of my problem. The problem states: Find the volume of the solid by the method of slicing.
The base is a circle of radius 8; slices made perpendicular to the base are squares. See the figure.

[image: Math Figure]

I believe that the Volume equation is: $\int_{-8}^8 (64-x^2)dx$.

But I am so confused on the height and how to get it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Since they are squares, the height is the same as the base. The base is a circle given by $x^2 + y^2 = 8^2$ or equivalently $y = \sqrt{64-x^2}$ for the top half of the circle.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about my little mistake. I was looking at the example in the book and that is where the 4 came from. So what you are saying is it would be $\int_{-8}^8 4(64-x^2)dx$

Comment: Now multiply the integrand by 4. $y$ is only half the square's side length.

Comment: So it would be $4[64x-1/3x^3]_{-8}^8$ I think I got it from here. Thank you guys for all of your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calc2 Slicing method to find volume](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947224/calc2-slicing-method-to-find-volume)